# Update a pyspark dataframe column, based on values match in another pyspark dataframe column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need help creating a new column `new_id` in a pyspark dataframe, whose value depend on a match of string type column `address` from another pyspark datafarame, and if it doesn´t have a match on the column `address`, then just fill with null.

Like the following:

df1:

```
  df1_value       address  new_id
          1   'street 57'    6248
          0   'street 99'    9543
          0   'street 23'    1673
          1   'street 14'    3557
```

df2:

```
   df2_value    old_id       address
          'A'   'A-12'   'street 57'
          'A'   'A-09'   'street 98'
          'B'     null   'street 23'
          'B'   'A-85'   'street 14'
          'A'     null   'street 82'
```

new_df2:

```
   df2_value    old_id       address  new_id
          'A'   'A-12'   'street 57'    6248
          'A'   'A-09'   'street 98'    null
          'B'     null   'street 23'    1673
          'B'   'A-85'   'street 14'    3557
          'A'     null   'street 82'    null
```

I know how to do this in python with a join, but I don´t know if there´s something similar in pyspark.

Comment: it's also a simple left join in pyspark. Please show what you have tried and what specific problem you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple left join. This should work:

```
df2.join(df1, "address", left).show()
```

Comment: Thanks @robert-kossendey. I did the join a bit different to prevent getting duplicate columns as follow:

`df2.alias("a").join(df1.alias("b"), df2['address'] == df1['address']).select("a.*", "b.new_id")`

Comment: No problem, if the answer helped you, an upvote would be appreciated